# Help With ATMega32 Fuses

Tags: avr, atmega, fuse-bits

I decided I wanted to learn Atmel Studio to be able to work with all their microcontrollers problem being i'm trying to use a brand new ATMega32 with default fuse settings and an external crystal clocked at 16MHz. Of course in software I set F_CPU to 16000000UL for delays, that didn't work. After looking around the internet I was told the MCU uses its internal oscillator rather than external and that i'd have to set it's fuse bits. I was directed to [AVR Fuse Calculator](http://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc), I determined that I should use this configuration:
[image: AVR Calculator]
Is Low Fuse Bit 0xFF and High Fuse Bit 0x99 okay to use? Or is there something that I missed? As I was quite confused while reading the fuse clocking bits.

Specs:
ATMega32,
16Mhz Crystal Oscillator,
22pF Ceramic Capacitors

Comment: In Atmel Studio, head to device programming, then proceed to the sub menu Fuses. In here, you can choose what fuses to set or not. There is a dropdown menu to select any crystal oscillator you use.

Comment: @LukwHappyValley thank you I don't know how I missed all this